# System of Nonlinear algebraic equations

Tags: nonlinear-system

If we reach the tolerance function in solving a system of non - linear equations from one point to the next, can it be said that the roots obtained are not converging at these points?

Comment: Not necessarily. The tolerance could be set too high, maybe more iterations are needed

Comment: @Yuriy S Thank you, By solving these equations in Mathematica, several roots are obtained, but from solving them in Matlab there is only one root, which from one step to the next the root has a negative value and the tolerance function appears. Can this be because of the convergence problem?

Comment: It could be. Would be better if you show the equations. Maybe even the code for Matlab... Don't forget that you can always check your solutions by substitution